# How can I delete all contacts synced by Outlook?

Tags: contacts, sync, outlook

I've added an outlook account to my phone running OxygenOS, which has synced its contacts into the contacts app.

How I can remove all of these synced contacts without deleting them one by one?

Comment: Try to turn off contact sync under settings->account->outlook.
it will do.

Comment: Will do what? Does turning off sync delete contacts already there? Really? Any reference you can give for that? Would surprise me.